# Spring Data JPA Interface Type Collection with ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I am developing Spring Boot app with Spring Data JPA and H2 database. I was writing my model entity classes and I got to the moment where I need to make ManyToMany relationship between `FreetimeActivity` and `Goal` entities. In `Goal` class I have collection of `Goalable` objects. `Goalable` is my interface. This interface is implemented by 3 classes. I want objects of any of this classes to be stored in that collection. `FreetimeActivity` is one of them (but the only implemented so far). Can Spring Data make some magic and make that kind of relationship for me or do I have to make separate colletion for all of these 3 classes and merge them into one interface type collection in the end?

I tried with `@ManyToMany` and `@JoinColumn` annotations and added some testing code to starting class, but when run It throws an exception:

`@OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.github.mesayah.assista.model.Goal.activityList[com.github.mesayah.assista.model.Goalable]`

Are there any annotations that can make that for me?

`FreetimeActivity.java`

```
package com.github.mesayah.assista.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Mesayah on 03.07.2017.
 */

@Entity
@Table(name = "freetime_activity")
public class FreetimeActivity extends Activity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "freetime_activities")
    private List<Goal> goals;


    @Override
    public long getId() {

        return id;
    }


    @Override
    public void setId(long id) {

        this.id = id;
    }


    @Override
    public String getName() {

        return name;
    }


    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {

        this.name = name;
    }


    public List<Goal> getGoals() {

        return goals;
    }


    public void setGoals(List<Goal> goalList) {

        this.goals = goalList;
    }


    public FreetimeActivity(String name) {


        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

`Goal.java`

```
package com.github.mesayah.assista.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Mesayah on 02.07.2017.
 */

@Entity
public class Goal {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "goal_freetime_activity", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "goal_id", referencedColumnName =
            "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "freetime_activity_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<FreetimeActivity> activityList;
    private List<Milestone> milestoneList;


    public Goal() {

    }


    public Goal(List<FreetimeActivity> activityList) {

        this.activityList = activityList;
    }


    public long getId() {

        return id;
    }


    public void setId(long id) {

        this.id = id;
    }


    public List<FreetimeActivity> getActivityList() {

        return activityList;
    }


    public void setActivityList(List<FreetimeActivity> activityList) {

        this.activityList = activityList;
    }


    public List<Milestone> getMilestoneList() {

        return milestoneList;
    }


    public void setMilestoneList(List<Milestone> milestoneList) {

        this.milestoneList = milestoneList;
    }
}
```

`AssistaApplication.java`

```
package com.github.mesayah.assista;

import com.github.mesayah.assista.model.Course;
import com.github.mesayah.assista.model.Exam;
import com.github.mesayah.assista.repository.CourseRepository;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.List;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.github.mesayah.assista.model")
public class AssistaApplication {

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AssistaApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(AssistaApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    @Transactional
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(CourseRepository courseRepository, ExamRepository examRepository) {
        return (args) -> {
            Course course = new Course("Dancing Course");
            Exam exam = new Exam("Dancing Test", course);

            // testing save
            courseRepository.save(course);
            examRepository.save(exam);

            course.getGrades().add(4.0);
            course.getGrades().add(4.5d);
            course.getGrades().add(3.5d);

            // testing update
            courseRepository.save(course);

            // using Spring Data JPA automated repositories
            List<Course> courses = (List<Course>) courseRepository.findAll();
            List<Exam> result = examRepository.findByCourse(course);
            Exam theExam = result.get(0);

            // testing relations
            logger.info("Courses in database: " + courses.size() + "\nExam's Course Id: " + theExam.getCourse().getId() + "\nCourse grades: " + theExam.getCourse().getGrades());
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgot the @Table annotation at your Goal class? Also the attribute `freetime_activity` you referenced in your mappedBy attribute does not exist in the goal class.

Comment: Hi, I reviewed my code and found that I am trying to make a collection of interface type objects. I've just edited the question. Now It's about if It's possible to automatically make that kind of relation with collection of interface type objects?

Comment: Any association annotated defining a JPA relation like `@ManyToMany` must have an entity on both ends. Therefore, both `Goal` and `Goalable` must be entities. They need to be annotated with either `@Entity` or `@MappedSuperclass`. Since neither can be used with annotations, `Goalable` must be a class. You can convert `Goalable` to an abstract class, annotate it with `@MappedSuperclass` and use it inside the `Goal` entity.